# Fill a list condition to another regarding values

Tags: python, list, random

I have the following question. I have 3 lists which are the below.

The list with Department Names:
`Department_List = ["Department_1", "Department_2"]
len("Department_List") = 2`

The list with Category Names:
`Category_List = ["Cat_1","Cat_3","Cat_1","Cat_2",....... ,"Cat_5"]
len("Category_List ") = 10000`

Empty List SubCategory:
`SubCategory_List = []`

The task i have to do is the following. I want to random fill the SubCategory_List with values from Department_List. The problem is that i want the same elements from the Category_List, to have the same values for Department Name.

For example, the outcome would be something like this in case that Cat_1 = Department_1,
Cat_3 = Department_2, Cat_2 = Department_2 and Cat_5 = Department_1:

`SubCategory_List = ["Department_1","Department_2","Department_1","Department_2",....... ,"Department_1"]`

Notice. I must not do it with Dictionary!

Thank you!

Comment: Cool. now that we know what you're after, show us what you've tried.

Comment: I am still unclear about what you result should be, you have a Subcategory_List which a list and you want a dict at the end. Please show a sample result, that should be too hard

Comment: Hello! I did it with dictionary but its not the way i need it. 

Ultimately, I try to make a dictionary,without using dictionary in python,by looping on lists!

As i mentioned, i have the list `Department_List = ["Department_1", "Department_2"]`. To make it different, assume the list `Category_List = ["Cat_1","Cat_3","Cat_1","Cat_2","Cat_2","Cat_3"]`. Note, i also have an empty list `SubCategory_List = []`. I want to fill the `SubCategory_List` randomly, with values from `Department_List ` but the common values to get the same values.

Comment: A **possible** expected outcome of the above, could be: `SubCategory_List = ["Department_1", "Department_2", "Department_1", "Department_2", "Department_2", "Department_2"]`

Comment: @LaSanton see my answer, it resolves your problem.

Comment: @MrNobody33 Hello sir! I just saw it but unfortunately its not right. In `Category _List` there are 2 values of `Cat_1` in 1st and 3rd place. But in the 1st and 3rd place of the `SubCategory_List` there are different values.

Comment: Check the last edit of my answer @LaSanton, maybe it's what you are looking for. I'm not sure yet how do you give the values of each category; with an input? with a list? with a dictionary?... So I assumed they're given by a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you

```
SubCategory_List = []

Department_List = ["Department_1", "Department_2"]

mydict = dict(SubCategory_List = Department_List )

print(mydict)
```

Output

```
{'SubCategory_List': ['Department_1', 'Department_2']}
```

---

Update

```
import random

SubCategory_List = []

Category_List = ["Cat_1","Cat_3","Cat_1","Cat_2","Cat_5"]

Department_List = ["Department_1", "Department_2"]

mydict = dict(SubCategory_List = {x:random.choice(Department_List) for x in Category_List})

print(mydict)
```

Output

```
{'SubCategory_List': {'Cat_1': 'Department_2', 'Cat_3': 'Department_1', 'Cat_2': 'Department_2', 'Cat_5': 'Department_2'}}
```

Run a 2nd time:

```
{'SubCategory_List': {'Cat_1': 'Department_1', 'Cat_3': 'Department_1', 'Cat_2': 'Department_1', 'Cat_5': 'Department_2'}}
```

Comment: I re-read your question. I added an update to my answer, as I believe this was what you were looking to do. Run it a few times and you will notice that subcategory is randomly filled with department list.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Department_List = ["Department_1", "Department_2"]

Category_List = ["Cat_1", "Cat_3", "Cat_1", "Cat_2", "Cat_5"]

sublist = {'SubCategory_List': [j for j in Department_List for i in Category_List if i[-2:] == j[-2:]]}

print(sublist)
```

Result:

```
{'SubCategory_List': ['Department_1', 'Department_1', 'Department_2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

To random fill the SubCategory_List with values from Department_List, with a length of `len(Category_List)` you could try this:

```
import random

Department_List = ["Department_1", "Department_2"]

Category_List = ["Cat_1","Cat_3","Cat_1","Cat_2","Cat_5"]


SubCategory_List = [Department_List[random.randint(0,1)] for i in Category_List]
print(SubCategory_List)
```

Output:

```
['Department_1', 'Department_2', 'Department_2', 'Department_2', 'Department_2']
```

If you want to fill the `SubCategory_List` based on given dictionary with the values you said, ( `Cat_1 = Department_1, Cat_3 = Department_2, Cat_2 = Department_2 and Cat_5 = Department_1`), you could try this:

```
Department_List = ["Department_1", "Department_2"]

Category_List = ["Cat_1","Cat_3","Cat_1","Cat_2","Cat_5"]

dct={'Cat_1':'Department_1', 'Cat_3':'Department_2', 'Cat_2':'Department_2', 'Cat_5': 'Department_1'}
SubCategory_List = [dct[i] for i in Category_List]
print(SubCategory_List)
```

Output:

```
['Department_1', 'Department_2', 'Department_1', 'Department_2', 'Department_1']
```

If you want to create that dictionary randomly, you can try this:

```
import random

#Create the dictionary randomly\\
Department_List = ["Department_1", "Department_2"]

Category_List = ["Cat_1","Cat_3","Cat_1","Cat_2","Cat_5"]

dct={i:Department_List[random.randint(0,1)] for i in Category_List}
print(dct)
SubCategory_List = [dct[i] for i in Category_List]
print(SubCategory_List)
```

Output:

```
dct
>>>{'Cat_1': 'Department_2', 'Cat_3': 'Department_2', 'Cat_2': 'Department_1', 'Cat_5': 'Department_1'}

SubCategory_List
>>>['Department_2', 'Department_2', 'Department_2', 'Department_1', 'Department_1']
```